# Creating a bootable USB Stick using OS X without sudo

Tags: macosx, usb-creator

I'm using OS X Mavericks and I have downloaded Ubuntu. I wish to use it as a USB stick, but I do not have sudo admin rights. Is there any other way to install it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need root privileges to format/copy to an USB Stick.

```
dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/devicename
```

This command copies your ISO onto the pendrive and makes it bootable. But be sure you have saved everything important from the USB Stick, because this command erases it, too.

Comment: It seems admin privileges are indeed needed. I get `dd: /dev/disk2: Permission denied` when attempting to `dd` an ISO to a USB drive.